# append cloned input to variable

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery variable:

```
var $items = "<input type='text' />";
```

and I have a cloned element:

```
var cloneA = $("#element").clone();
```

I cannot find a way to append cloneA to $items.

What could be the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, you have a JavaScript variable, not a jQuery one. (There is no such thing as the latter). Secondly, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You can't append a DOM element to a string. Even if your string was an element (an `input`), they are self-closing elements and you cannot append children to them. Please edit the question to clarify your intention.

Comment: As @Utkanos said, you can't append elements to an `<input>` element. Did you instead mean that you want to append the input to the clone of `#element`?

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm just a newbie. And I am still exploring things in jquery. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @comebal - could you please update your post after reading our comments and questions?  It is still not clear exactly what you were trying to accomplish.  You could possibly add some example HTML and how you want the results to look...

Comment: @comebal...did you read our comments and find one acceptable?  I'm dying to know who owes who a plus one here haha.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I placed who answered my question. I'll go answer it now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you were not using `$items` as a jQuery object.  You need it to be a jQuery object in order to use the `.append()` function on it.

Wrapping the HTML string in the jQuery variable, `$` will create an object with that HTML inside.

Try this -

```
var $items = $("<input type='text' />");
var cloneA = $("#element").clone();
$items.append(cloneA);
```

---

I assume that this is simply pseudo code because you wouldn't regularly want to be appending elements *into* an `<input>` element.  Rather adding `<input>` fields into an existing element...

Something slightly more logical would look like this -

```
var $items = $("<div id="input_holder"></div>");

// #element in this example is an actual <input> 
var cloneA = $("#element").clone(); element.

$items.append(cloneA);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$items`  is not a jQuery selector it is only a string. To make it a valid jQuery object you can use `append()` on update the code to:

```
var $items = $("<input type='text' />");
```

Then you should be able to append the clone:

```
var cloneA = $("#element").clone();

$items.append(cloneA);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are wanting to ADD the cloned element to the selction?

```
var $items = $('<input type="text"/>');
var cloneA = $('#element').clone();
$items = $items.add(cloneA); //items now has the input and #element
```

Comment: This will not add the content of one element to another.  It will create an array containing two elements that are independent of each other

Comment: I didn't say it would.  I said that it will add the cloned element TO THE SELECTION, which is what I believe comebal is wanting to do for 2 reasons: 1) he/she's calling the variable $items 2) you can't append items to an input element...at least not in a valid way.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your assumption is correct.  [I've requested some clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845128/append-cloned-input-to-variable#comment15757230_11845128) from the OP so hopefully we'll find out soon enough.

Comment: Oh it's on :)  Winner take all.